# Logging whole model shows different values than logging specific property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm sorry if I can't be of more help, but I appreciate any theories of what could be happening here.

I have this piece of code inside my typescript file:

```
this.model.presupuesto.value = { min: minBudget, max: maxBudget };
this.model.presupuesto.selected = [ minBudget, maxBudget ];

console.log('LOADED MODEL', this.model, this.model.presupuesto.selected);
```

There isn't anything in between those lines of code.

I'm getting the following log:

[image: Screenshot]

How can these two values be different?

As I understand, they should be pointing to the same object.

## Update

Adding logs for:

```
console.log('LOADED MODEL', this.model, this.model.presupuesto, this.model.presupuesto.selected, this.model.presupuesto.selected[0], this.model.presupuesto.selected[1]);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the value of `this.model.presupuesto.selected[1]` ? In other words, are you hunting a real bug, or just a weird misbehavior of the browser console?

Comment: @PavelZdenek This is actually a real bug. The model's view is actually showing the array as `[0, 0]` and I don't know why

Comment: Are you more interested in what is the console showing, or what the value really holds? Try this `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model.presupuesto))` and tell me what it shows.

Comment: @PavelZdenek `{"type":1,"value":{"min":0,"max":4000000},"selected":[0,4000000],"title":"Presupuesto"}`

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is asynchronous. It must be, it can't afford to block the runtime single thread by serializing your whole complex data. So if the logged JS Object is fairly complex, `console.log` snapshots only the higher levels of it. When you drill down the structure by expanding arrows, you may reach the level where console fills the rest with the *latest data, not the data of the `console.log` moment*.

So what happened in your case?

1. `maxBudget` was 4000000 and you filled `presupuesto`.
2. you logged complex objects, and simple(r) values too. Arrays are simple enough to get serialized right away, objects not.
3. milliseconds pass
4. your webpage code sets `this.model.presupuesto.selected[1] = 0`
5. milliseconds pass
6. you inspect the complex Object in browser console

**Solution**: do not log complex objects. Use `JSON.stringify` if you must.